# Github Actions: npm process completed with exit code 1

Tags: node.js, npm, github-actions

While running `npm run prod` in my app, I get the error:

```
> prod
> npm run production


> production
> cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
npx browserslist@latest --update-db

Why you should do it regularly:
https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#browsers-data-updating
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I checked log file and I see the following,

```
 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'run', 'prod' ]
1 info using npm@8.5.5
2 info using node@v16.15.0
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 1ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 4ms
5 timing config:load:file:/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/npmrc Completed in 39ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 40ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 2ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
9 timing config:load:file:/home/act/actions-runner/_work/myapp/myapp/.npmrc Completed in 0ms
10 timing config:load:project Completed in 5ms
11 timing config:load:file:/home/act/.npmrc Completed in 1ms
12 timing config:load:user Completed in 1ms
13 timing config:load:file:/usr/etc/npmrc Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:global Completed in 1ms
15 timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
16 timing config:load:credentials Completed in 1ms
17 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 2ms
18 timing config:load Completed in 58ms
19 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 58ms
20 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 1ms
21 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 5ms
22 timing npm:load:display Completed in 6ms
23 verbose logfile /home/act/.npm/_logs/2022-05-04T09_11_43_397Z-debug-0.log
24 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 7ms
25 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 1ms
26 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
27 timing npm:load Completed in 74ms
28 silly logfile start cleaning logs, removing 1 files
29 timing command:run Completed in 133777ms
30 verbose exit 1
31 timing npm Completed in 134306ms
32 verbose code 1
```

I also ran `npm cache clean --force` and `rm -rf node_modules` before and I still get the same error.